# Skype Web SDK - Maintain a user session

Tags: javascript, skype, skype-for-business

I am using Skype Web SDK to get a user's contact list in the following manner.

```
Skype.initialize({
                 apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255',
                 }, function (api) {
                        var Application = api.application;
                        var client = new Application();
                        client.signInManager.signIn({
                            username: sip,
                            password: pwd
                        })
```

This works fine when I provide the username(sip) and password. However, when I reload the page, I have to provide the credentials again because the app re-initializes. Is there a way to maintain the user's sessions for a while after the initial login so that the page refreshes wouldn't need ask for credentials again?

I have looked through the samples and docuementation that Microsoft has and couldn't find a way. I've also tried to store the `client` object in the `localStorage` after the initialization and sign in, but when I tried to reuse the object from localStorage to get the contact list, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

http://officedev.github.io/skype-docs/Skype/WebSDK/model/api/interfaces/jcafe.signinmanager.html#signin last example explains that you can store oauth token and use it as unexpired token.

> To connect to an existing app's event channel, specify id of that app:

```js
sm.signIn({
    username: "user1@company.com",
    password: "password1",
    id: "273867-234235-45346345634-345"
});
```

> To sign in to Skype for Business Online using OAuth while handling the
>   logic of retrieving OAuth tokens yourself:

```js
 sm.signIn({
 client_id: '123-456',
 origins: [ 'https://webdir.online.lync.com/AutoDiscover/AutoDiscoverservice.svc/root' ],
 cors: true,
 get_oauth_token: function(resource) {
     // Return a valid unexpired token for the specified resource if you already have one.
     // Else, return a promise and resolve it once you have obtained a token.
     return 'Bearer eyJ0e...';
 }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure if I completely understand the answer. In the first example, where do I get the id from? In the second example, where do I get the OAuth token from?